# How to clear an input value on some button press?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to clear an input when a user presses comma (<kbd>,</kbd>). So what I did was, on `(keypress)` I would check the `keyCode` and if it's a comma I would clear the input by setting the input value to `input.value = ''`.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" #elem (keypress)="clearInput($event)">
```

Code:

```
@ViewChild( 'elem' ) public element;

clearInput( e: KeyboardEvent ) {
 if ( e.keyCode === 44 ) {
    this.element.nativeElement.value = '';
 } else {
   console.log('Not a comma');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Use [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Add `preventDefault()` in your `clearInput` code as shown below:

```
clearInput (e: KeyboardEvent) {
   if (e.keyCode === 44) {
      e.preventDefault();     // <-- Here
      this.element.nativeElement.value = '';
   } else {
      console.log('Not a comma');
   }
}
```

Comment: You could add some explanation: The insertion of the comma will be triggered by the same "keyup" event as your code. But the Browser has to run your code first, since your listener is not passive (it might preventDefault() or return false) - so the keypress event will run your listener first (clear the field) and then the default listener (inserting a comma into the empty field). So other solutions would be **keyUp** or marking your listener **passive**. - But preventDefault() is most idiomatic for your case.

Answer (score 7):

Simply `return false` if a comma is pressed:

```js
class HomeComponent {
  @ViewChild('elem') public element;
  clearInput(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.keyCode === 44) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = '';
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('Not a comma');
    }
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lucakiebel/zrehcwfy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 minor changes:

1. Use `keyup` event to get the latest key typed and include in the value of `input`
2. Use `e.key === ','` in the `if` condition

Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g5nd2ums/)