# How to configure event listeners in HTML itself?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, dom-events

Giving you an example, we can do something like the following to make our listeners trigger only in the event capturing phase:

```
element.addEventListener(event, function, true);
```

Or,

```
element.addEventListener(event, function, {passive: true});
```

..to make the listener passive. But, these all settings are only limited to setting 'em up through JavaScript code. What if, we are adding a listener to a DOM element in our HTML/Template code like:

```
<element onevent="function">
```

How can we make all those settings on listeners in this case? These setting are desirable especially when we are using frameworks like **React** where we use to attach event handlers directly in our template only and almost never using `element.addEventListener()`.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with HTML attributes. If you need that level of control, you have to use Javascript.

Comment: In that case, you could only check the [`eventPhase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase) inside your handler function, and then based on that decide whether/how to proceed. But do you really still want to use “inline” event handling in this day & age …?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, Sir. But, I would wait for someone who might be knowing the answer to this (if exists). Do you mind upvoting this post so that other users can notice this and post an answer if they actually know? :)

Comment: BTW, `event="function"` should be `onevent="function()"`.

Comment: @Barmar Corrected! Thanks :)

Comment: @CBroe I was actually trying to reply to a comment on my answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744747/clearing-an-input-on-comma-press-doesnt-clear-the-comma/51744903?noredirect=1#comment90457484_51744903 That's the reason I really want to know how to do this.

Comment: A hacky solution that probably shouldn't be used would be to insert a `<script>` tag right after the element, and have that script attach the listener as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React provides you a way to use events in the capture phase by appending `Capture` at the end of event name.

As per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events):

> The event handlers are triggered by an event in the bubbling phase. To
>   register an event handler for the capture phase, append Capture to the
>   event name; for example, instead of using `onClick`, you would use
>   `onClickCapture` to handle the click event in the capture phase.

Comment: And what about making the listeners passive?

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta there has been a thread going on in react github for supporting this. However its still WIP. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6436 Also browsers support passive: true by default on wheel and scroll events

Answer (score 1):

Directly in HTML it is not possible.

But using JavaScript this is very simple like follows:

1. You have to write all your event settings to HTML element attributes;
2. Then you can read all this attributes and create an event listener.

**Snippet example**

```js
function myFunction()
{
    console.log('it works!');
}

var myelements = document.querySelectorAll('myelement');
for(var i = myelements.length; i--;)
{
    var eventName = myelements[i].getAttribute('event-name'),
        eventFunction = myelements[i].getAttribute('event-function-name'),
        eventSetting = myelements[i].getAttribute('event-setting');

    eventFunction = window[eventFunction];
    eventSetting = eventSetting.indexOf('{') == 0 ? JSON.parse(eventSetting) : !!eventSetting;
    //if e.g. eventSetting == "true" then after !!eventSetting it will be a boolean true

    myelements[i].addEventListener(eventName, eventFunction, eventSetting);
}
```

```css
myelement
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<myelement event-name="click"
        event-function-name="myFunction"
        event-setting='{"passive":true}'></myelement>
```